# Google Maps - Get all street Names for a particular postcode

Tags: ios, google-maps

In my iOS app, I have to retrieve all the street names of a particular postcode. For Eg, if I enter "kt3 6dw", I have to get the street names such as "Chatsworth Gardens" and so on. I have tried a lot with google maps, but cudnt retrieve such Info. Any ideas on this ??

Comment: if u pass the postcode u surely get the all street name related about the post code

Comment: I m not getting the street names, only till new malden.. and i cudnt zoom in after that.. i used autocomplete places for this, and using the reference , called places details, but didn't get any street address.

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [_httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path: @"maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?components=country:UK" parameters:parameters];

Comment: NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;
    [ parameters setObject:@"false" forKey:@"sensor"] ;
    [ parameters setObject:@"AIzaSyDA3hDY08KopU8GZ4IhcAeOPmBBFXtPE4c" forKey:@"key"] ; 
    [ parameters setObject:textFieldText forKey:@"input"] ;
and these are the params...